# Laravel 5.4 Reverse eloquent relationship Error

Tags: php, eloquent, foreign-keys, laravel-5.4

why i have this error in my reverse eloquent relationship in Laravel 5.4

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` = 1 limit 1)'
```

i have this code:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{

    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class,'category_id');
    }
}
```

Category Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{

  protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';

  public function product() 
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'category_id');
  }
}
```

when i execute in tinker

```
App\Product::find(1)->category;
```

the error occurs.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Check if there is a product with id 1 in ur database.

Comment: @adamyi i am making reverse eloquent. i want to find a product that has category of 1

Comment: `Product::find(1)->category` means to get the category of product whose id = 1. U need to write `Category::find(1)->product`, which should return a collection for u

Comment: Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`id` = 1 limit 1)'

Comment: @adamyi thanks for your reply. what i mean is i am trying to make reverse. please take a look in my code

Comment: @adamyi i updated my question